# How to programmatically check for latest version of given jar in the market?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-central, gradle-dependencies

I need to upgrade my server infrastructure to use latest 3rd party binaries , Since that number > 1000 this becomes very hectic , troublesome and error prone to manually check for individually at their site and upgrade them .

Is there any way i can check for its latest version programmatically
Eg . I am using Spring Core 4.1.4 i write some program which gives me some name Spring core , I make a request to maven central to give me the latest version of Spring-core AND I dump its output to some csv etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is already using Maven, you can use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). It can update this for you.

Comment: We are using gradle

Comment: Yeah... well... for gradle I wouldn't know, sorry...